# Search up definitions

Tags: livescript

This is my code for livescript:

```
                        if (res = json.msg.match /^iSearchup\s(.*)$/i)? then
                            getReq("[url='http://urbanscraper.herokuapp.com/define/'][http://urbanscraper.herokuapp.com/define/[/url]" + encodeURIComponent(msg.splice(1, msg.length - 1).join(" ")) + ".json", function(res, passback)
                            if (res.word && res.definition){
                                @socket.send JSON.stringify {
                                    type: \pmsg
                                    nick: 'iPoddy:'
                                    msg: json.from + ": " + res.word + " - " + res.definition
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                @socket.send JSON.stringify {
                                    type: \pmsg
                                    nick: 'iPoddy:'
                                    msg: json.from + ":  Sorry, no results were returned."
                                }
                            }
```

That is my code. It gave me the error "dedent" but I fixed it and it still give me that error again. Help?

Answer (score 2):

You have several errors in this code. It will give you an error of `UNEXPECTED DEDENT` because you are mixing spaces and tabs and LiveScript is a whitespace-strict programming language. So on, avoid the use of brackets while using LiveScript. Remember also that in a conditional structure, like `if`, you might use `then` after. This will not compile due to:

- Mixing spaces and tabs
- `else` keyword with brackets
- Expecting `then` after expression to determine condition
- **Syntax Error** in `function(res, passback)`

And you have some **little** issues and not standardized practices:

- Using assignment operator `=` instead of `==|~=` for comparasion
- Using an invalid lambda expression as a parameters in `function(res, passback)`
- Using `+` to concat, instead of `++`
- Using `&&` operator, instead of `and`
- Using parentheses to encapsulate a single expression in the first conditional

This should work well:

```
if res ~= json.msg.match /^iSearchup\s(.*)$/i then
    url = "[url='http://urbanscraper.herokuapp.com/define/'][http://urbanscraper.herokuapp.com/define/[/url]"
    getReq <| url ++ encodeURIComponent(msg.splice(1 msg.length - 1).join(" ")) ++ ".json"
    if res.word && res.definition then
        @socket.send <| JSON.stringify(
            type: \pmsg
            nick: 'iPoddy:'
            msg: json.from ++ ": " ++ res.word ++ " - " ++ res.definition
        )
    else
        @socket.send <| JSON.stringify (
            type: \pmsg
            nick: 'iPoddy:'
        msg: json.from ++ ":  Sorry, no results were returned."
        )
```